# submit dynamic form with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, submit

When I want to submit a form with my js i always get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null

its like the js doesnt find the form

Here the js code:

```js
echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>";
echo "function send(ak,id){";
echo   "document.getElementById('java').submit(); ";
echo "document.write('submited');";
echo"}";
echo "</script>";
```

And here the php / html:

```html
   echo "<form id='java' method='post' action='reisegruppe.php' >";
   echo "<input name='ak' type='hidden' />";
   echo "<input name='id' type='hidden' />";    
    
// Reisegruppe ausgeben
if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
    // Reisegruppe ID , von , nach ausgeben
    $count = 1;
    while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        
        echo "<br>" . "id: " . $row1["reisegruppe_id"]. 
             " - <b> von: </b> " .'<b>'.'<input name="von" value='.$row1["von"].' size="5" />'.'</b>'. " " .
             "<b>nach: </b>" .'<b>'.'<input size="5" name="nach" value='. $row1["nach"].'>'.'</b>'." ". "<br>";
     
        echo "<a href='javascript:send(1,32)';>neu eintragen</a>";
        
      
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){     
            if($row1["reisegruppe_id"] == $row["FK_reisegruppe_id"]){                
           echo  " - Name: " . $row["vorname"]. " " . $row["nachname"]. " " . "<br>";}    
        }
        
        $sql = "SELECT reisegruppe_id, von, nach,teilnehmer_id, vorname, nachname,FK_reisegruppe_id FROM Reisegruppe JOIN Teilnehmer on FK_reisegruppe_id = reisegruppe_id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
          
    }
    
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}


echo </form>;
```

Comment: The last PHP line should be `echo '</form>';` otherwise the form is not completed and does not exist.

Comment: echo "</form>";  it is at the end

Comment: are you executing your javascript code BEFORE the form  was't actually created. Or after form

Comment: im executing it with the link : echo "<a href='javascript:send(1,32)';>neu eintragen</a>"; there the form already exists

Comment: echo "document.write('submited');"; remove this line and ur function is good to go..

Comment: perfect thank you!  why cant i do this? echo "document.write('submited');";

Comment: because it's stop the page to go next page. if my comment help kindly accept my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

comment this line because it is stop the `from` from `submitting`

```
echo "document.write('submited');";
```